# Do you use any out-of-browser Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

I know a lot of Adobe Flex out-of-browser applications, almost all of them being Twitter clients :)

But I haven't yet seen even one out-of-browser Silverlight application yet.

Do you use any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seesmic.com provides a desktop client for twitter using silverlight I think!

Answer (score 0):

[Logitech Harmony Configuration Utility](http://myharmony.com/InstallSoftware.aspx). It is connecting to the remote using USB from the pretty low trusted sandbox. Nice.